# Entire lits gets updated with same dict

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo, pymongo-3.x

I am inserting into new table  and I am using python to insert.

```
What Am I trying to do?
```

I have a json file which is "a" and it has key "MCA Governance Entity" and "Assessment Unit"
and I have a list called MGE
so I am trying to loop through MGE and generate document with updated values and insert into database.
My code is as :

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd
import pandasql as pf
import json
import random
foo = random.SystemRandom()
from pymongo.errors import BulkWriteError
a=[{
  "ARCM Summary": {
    "MCA Governance Entity": "600703 - NAM ",
    "Assessment Unit": "500043 - NAM - US Utility",
    "Activity Instance ID": 1234,
    "Risk Instance ID": 1234,
    "Control Instance ID": 1234,
    "Monitoring Instance ID": 1234,
    "Total Activity Check": "Pass",
    "Risk Check": "Fail",
    "Total Control Check": "Fail",
    "Total Monitoring Check": "Fail",
    "Total ARCM Check": "Fail",
    "Week": "2021-05-10",
    "Activity Checks": {
      "Activity Check": [
        {
          "Description": "Activity Description contains > 20 words",
          "Check": "Pass"
        },
        {
          "Description": "Frequency within Activity decsription matches Activity Frequency",
          "Check": "Pass"
        }
      ]
    },
    "Risk Checks": {
      "Risk Check": [
        {
          "Description": "Risk Description contains > 20 words",
          "Check": "Pass"
        },
        {
          "Description": "Freq of undelrlying process matches Activity Frequency",
          "Check": "Pass"
        },
        {
          "Description": "Regulatory Environment rating 'High'",
          "Check": "Fail"
        },
        {
          "Description": "Geopolitical Environment rating 'Medium'",
          "Check": "Pass"
        },
        {
          "Description": "Anticipated Freq of Op Risk Event less frequent/equal to both Activity Frequency and Freq of Underlying Process",
          "Check": "Pass"
        },
        {
          "Description": "Inherent Risk Tier 4-5 and no open L 1-3 issues are mapped",
          "Check": "Fail"
        },
        {
          "Description": "Regulatory Impact aligned with Regulatory Tier of mapped Publications / Obligations",
          "Check": "N/A"
        }
      ]
    },
    "Control Checks": {
      "Control Check": [
        {
          "Description": "Control Description contains > 20 words",
          "Check": "Pass"
        },
        {
          "Description": "Freq within Control descriptions matches Control Frequency",
          "Check": "Pass"
        },
        {
          "Description": "Conrol frequency within 2 deviations of Activity frequency",
          "Check": "Pass"
        },
        {
          "Description": "Control Attribute = 'Automated' and critical applications exist",
          "Check": "NA"
        },
        {
          "Description": "Control design rating = 'Adequate' and no open L1-3 issues mapped",
          "Check": "NA"
        }
      ]
    },
    "Monitoring Checks": {
      "Monitoring Check": [
        {
          "Description": "Monitoring Description contains > 20 words",
          "Check": "Pass"
        },
        {
          "Description": "Frequency within Monitoring tool decsription matches Monitoring Tool Frequency",
          "Check": "Pass"
        },
        {
          "Description": "Monitoring tool Frequency within 2 deviations of control frequency",
          "Check": "Fail"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "Details": {
    "Sub Group": "USCB",
    "Critical Applications": "",
    "Critical Ext Third Parties": "",
    "In Scope Flag": "No",
    "Inherent Risk Rating": "Tier 5",
    "Residual Risk Rating": "Tier 5",
    "Monitoring Result": "Pass"
  },
  "Activity Details": {
    "Activity Level 1": "Risk Management",
    "Activity Level 2": "Operational Risk Management",
    "Activity Level 3": "",
    "Activity SMP Description": "",
    "Activity AU Description": "Model Development Data Sourcing Transmission: On an daily basis (event driven) basis the RMU data and technology team loads incoming data for use in model development. This is done on behalf of the risk modeling utility in order to ensure modeling data sets have been transmitted successfully with complete data for model development.",
    "Activity AU Frequency": "Daily",
    "Activity Status": "Active"
  },
  "Risk Details": {
    "Risk Level 1": "Model Risk",
    "Risk Level 2": "Model Design and Implementation Risk",
    "Risk Level 3": "",
    "Risk Level 4": "",
    "Risk SMP Description": "",
    "Risk AU Description": "Throughout the data load process there is potential for data translation errors when creating SAS datasets from text files. If the risk materializes this could result in improper model development.",
    "Regulatory Environment Rating": "Low",
    "Geopolitical Environmnt Rating": "Medium",
    "Business Environment Rating": "Medium",
    "Freq Of Underlying Process": "Daily",
    "Anticipated Freq:Op Risk Event": "Daily",
    "Financial Operational Loss": "<$100M",
    "Regulatory Impact": "Low",
    "Reputational Impact": "Low",
    "Business Damage": "Low",
    "Conduct Risk": "Low",
    "Risk Status": "Active",
    "Regulation Tier (Highest)": "N/A"
  },
  "Control Details": {
    "Control Type": "Verifications",
    "Control SMP Description": "",
    "Control AU Description": "On a daily basis (event driven), the RMU Data and technology team compares the content of raw files to the fields in the resulting SAS dataset. SAS logs are also checked for any errors encountered during the load process. The process is completed on the RMU server for each SAS data set or raw data file transmitted. This control is executed in order to ensure there are no transmission errors or load errors in the modeling data. Evidence of control is stored in RMU server log files.",
    "Control AU Frequency": "Daily",
    "Control AU Attributes": "Manual-Detective",
    "Missing Control Indicator": "No",
    "Control Status": "Active",
    "# Open Issues L1-L3": 1,
    "# Events >$100K pst 3 mth": "",
    "Control Design Rating": "Adequate"
  },
  "Monitoring Details": {
    "Monitoring Tool": "Testing",
    "Monitoring Tool SMP Desc": "",
    "Monitoring Tool AU Description": "On a monthly basis the RMU MCA Monitoring Analyst will verify there are no model data load errors for a sample of files loaded. The monitoring checks that the control is executed as intended by 1) Obtain random sample of data loads for month of interest, total of 20 samples. 2) Obtain the location or copies of the associated SAS logs. 3) Review the SAS logs. Are there any errors or warnings that indicate data quality was compromised during the load process? 4) Obtain the location or copies of the associated SAS outputs(1st). 5) Review the sample PROC PRINT output. If the data load involved translating a text file into a SAS dataset or had any data manipulation coding, does the SAS output indicate the data was loaded improperly(e.g. are the field values inconsistent with the variable name or label)? An answer of 'Yes' to questions 3 or 5 would constitute a fail for that particular sample. Control Breach: Greater than 10% of files sampled reveal load errors for two or more consecutive months. Evidence of monitoring is stored in RMU MCA SharePoint.",
    "Monitoring Tool AU Frequency": "Monthly",
    "Monitoring Tool Status": "Active",
    "Monitoring Design Rating": "Adequate",
    "Monitoring Attribute": "#N/A"
  },
  "Other": {
    "Standard MCA Profile(SMP)Name": "",
    "Enterprise MCA Profile Name": "",
    "Emerging Risk Indicator": "No",
    "Taxonomy Risk Description": "Risk that the model may have fundamental errors and may produce inaccurate outputs when viewed against the design objective and intended business uses.",
    "Sox/ICFR Control": "NA",
    "Critical Int Service Providers": "",
    "Critical Internal Clients": ""

     }
    }   ]
MGE=[
  {
'600703 - NAM - US - GCB - US Consumer Bank - Credit Risk':['500043 - NAM - US - GCB Consumer Risk - Credit Risk - Risk Modeling Utility',
                                                            '503014 - NAM - US - GCB - US Consumer Bank - Citi Branded Cards - Credit Risk']},
  {'600286 - NAM - US - GCB - US Consumer Bank - Citi Branded Cards':['503017 - NAM - US - GCB - US Consumer Bank - Citi Branded Cards - Product Management'
                                                                        ,'503018 - NAM - US - GCB - US Consumer Bank - Citi Branded Cards - Loyalty Programs'
                                                                        ,'503020 - NAM - US - GCB - US Consumer Bank - Citi Branded Cards - Pricing and Statement Operations']},
  {'600595 - NAM - US - GCB - US Consumer Bank - USRB': ['503022 - NAM - US - GCB - US Consumer Bank - USRB - Personal Wealth Management']},
  {'600288 - NAM - US - GCB - Citi Retail Services' :['503023 - NAM - US - GCB - Citi Retail Services - Business Operations'
                                                    ,   '503028 - NAM - US - GCB - Citi Retail Services - Strategic Initiatives'
                                                    ,   '503029 - NAM - US - GCB - Citi Retail Services - Partner Management']},
  {'600703 - NAM - US - GCB - US Consumer Bank - Credit Risk'   :['503030 - NAM - US - GCB - US Consumer Bank - Citi Retail Services - Credit Risk']}
]
client = MongoClient("mongodb://*******")
db = client["qc_1"]
out_col = db["Done_done"]
d=[]
def fake(a):
        for i in a:
            for x in MGE:
                  c = 0
                  for t in x:
                     for u in x[t]:
                        i["ARCM Summary"].update({"MCA Governance Entity":t})
                        i["ARCM Summary"].update({"Assessment Unit":x[t][c]})
                        i["ARCM Summary"].update({"Activity Instance ID":foo.randint(50000,100000)})
                        i["ARCM Summary"].update({"Risk Instance ID": foo.randint(50000,100000)})
                        i["ARCM Summary"].update({"Control Instance ID": foo.randint(50000,100000)})
                        i["ARCM Summary"].update({"Monitoring Instance ID": foo.randint(50000,100000)})
                        c=c+1
                        out_col.insert_one(i)
        return d
d=fake(a)
print("Done")
```

Error:

```
raise DuplicateKeyError(error.get("errmsg"), 11000, error)
pymongo.errors.DuplicateKeyError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: qc_summary.Arcm_test index: _id_ dup key: { _id: ObjectId('60c29bf4084e579c8bc4e1b1') }, full error: {'index': 0, 'code': 11000, 'keyPattern': {'_id': 1}, 'keyValue': {'_id': ObjectId('60c29bf4084e579c8bc4e1b1')}, 'errmsg': "E11000 duplicate key error collection: qc_summary.Arcm_test index: _id_ dup key: { _id: ObjectId('60c29bf4084e579c8bc4e1b1') }"}
```

Comment: Can you please check your schema once, whether you have added `unique: true` for the field you are getting in error. It's saying that the field is already there in the collection.

Comment: I found out that, if one value gets updated entire list has same dict, how to no update other records?